# UIMenuController and TapGesture reappears on movement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer, uimenucontroller

I am handling a `UITapGesture` on `UITableView` and displaying a `UIMenuController` on the selected `UITableViewCell`. When I select and the menu appears, if I move the finger over the cell it seems that the menu it's constantly appearing and I don't like how it looks at all.

There is some way to avoid that?

Thank you!

**Tap gesture code (Swift 2.3):**

```
let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5 
longPressGesture.delegate = self
self.messagesTableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I have solved like this:

**Swift 2**

Declaring this global variable

```
var menuControllerOpened:Bool = false
```

Making a block on tagGestureHandler:

```
func handleLongPress(longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if !self.menuControllerOpened {
        let p = longPressGesture.locationInView(self.messagesTableView)
        self.selectedIndexPathMenu = self.messagesTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(p)
        if self.selectedIndexPathMenu != nil {
            //Do something you want
            let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
            let reportItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Reportar usuario", action: #selector(reportMessageItem))
            menu.menuItems = [reportItem]
            menu.setTargetRect(cell.frame, inView: self.messagesTableView)
            menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

But configuring some notification events, which will handle when a MenuController is show or hide:

```
func configureMenuControllerEvents() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleMenuControllerShow), name: UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleMenuControllerHide), name: UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification, object: nil)

}

func handleMenuControllerShow() {
    self.menuControllerOpened = true
}

func handleMenuControllerHide() {
    self.menuControllerOpened = false
}
```